# firebase.auth().signInAnonymously() restrictions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Currently, I have a page were I user goes through `signInWithPhoneNumber()` phone verification in order to gain access. I am thinking of using `signInAnonymously()` so that they don't have to share any personal info and shorten the flow process.

With `signInWithPhoneNumber()` I could just add the number to a block list if they spam this form they would need to use a new number.

What measures can I **(if any)** put in place to stop or make it harder a user from creating multiple anonymous profiles and spamming this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a lot you can do in your application code beyond what Firebase Authentication already does for you for abuse prevention. This would actually be one great reason to require users to sign-in with credentials, instead of relying on anonymous authentication.

Typically you'd give anonymous users much lower quota in your app, and (in a friendly way) tell users to sign in with credentials to get a higher quota.